# How to get the button to toggle between F and C?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was able to get the temperature to switch between Fahrenheit and Celcius. However, I wasn't able to get the small ball/button to move back and forth between F and C.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var mainCities = {
    'San Francisco' : {
      'region': 'California',
      'country': "United States",
      'lat': 37.7749300,
      'lon': -122.4194200
    },
    'St. Louis': {
      'region': 'Missouri',
      'country': "United States",
      'lat': 38.6272700,
      'lon': -90.1978900
    },
    'Miami': {
      'region': 'Florida',
      'country': "United States",
      'lat': 25.7742700,
      'lon': -80.1936600
    },
    'Tokyo': {
      'region': 'Tokyo',
      'country': "Japan",
      'lat': 35.689500,
      'lon': 139.6917100
    }
  }
  
  var currentLat;
  var currentLong;
  
  function getLocation() {
    $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
      
      //var currentRegion = data.regionName;
      var currentCity = data.city;
      currentLat = data.lat;
      currentLong = data.lon;
      
      $("#cityname").text(currentCity);
      
      getWeather();
      
    });
  }
  
function getWeather() {
  
  $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + currentLat + '&lon=' + currentLong + '&units=imperial&APPID=e656b9ee098cf2341fcfdb365b96b4a8', function(json) {
    
    var showfahrenheit = true;
    var tempfahrenheit = Math.round(json.main.temp);
    var temcelcius = Math.round((tempfahrenheit - 32) * 5/9);
    
    $("#temp").html(tempfahrenheit);
    
    $('#unit-switch').on('click', function() {
      if (showfahrenheit === false) {
        $("#temp").html(tempfahrenheit);
        showfahrenheit = true;
      } else {
        $("#temp").html(temcelcius); 
        showfahrenheit = false;
      }
      
      $("#unit-toggle").toggleClass("toggle");
   //$('#temp').toggleClass('toggle');
    });
    
  });
};
  
  $(".cityarea").html(getLocation);
  
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
body {
  position: relative;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
}
.header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.weatherbox {
  text-align: center;
}
.cityarea h2 {
  color: #000000;
}
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}
input[type=checkbox]{
  display: none;
}
label{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #57A0D4;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
label .fa-globe {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
/*  The ul will have display:none by default */
ul{
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
ul li{
  /*padding: 15px;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #4FB9A7;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #4FB9A7;
  color: #FFF;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
  background-color: #3D88BD;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
ul .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.temperaturearea span#temp {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 80px;
}
.temperaturearea #temp:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 16px;
    right: -17px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.weather > span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.weather > span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.main-toggle span {
  margin: 0 0 0 16px;
}
.main-toggle span:last-child {
  margin-left: 11px;
}
.weather button {
  background: #6bbf6b;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s;
}
.weather button:active {
  background: #67b567;
 }
.weather #unit-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -8px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: left .2s;
}
.toggle {
  left: 27px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"><h1>Local Weather</h1></div>
    <div class="weatherbox">
      <div class="cityarea">
      <h2 id="cityname"></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="countryarea">
        <h3 id="state"></h3>
        <h3 id="country"></h3>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="dropdownlocation">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-toggle">
    <label for="checkbox-toggle"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Current Location</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main Cities</a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
      </div>
      </div>-->
    <div class="temperaturearea">
      <div>
      <span id="wicon"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="wdescription"></div>
      <span id="temp"></span>
      <div class="weather main-toggle"> <!-- Begin Unit Switch -->
      <span>F</span>
      <button id="unit-switch"><span id="unit-toggle"></span></button>
      <span>C</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can even check out my code at Codepen: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/EZMJZw

What did I miss? I'm trying to toggleClass using the class .toggle everytime I use #unit-switch to click on.

Comment: Why did you change the question??? I'm only showing the specific code in relation to the question I'm asking.

Comment: @KristinaBressler Because it's better to post a working example of your question here, rather than through some external link. That way, if the external link becomes invalid in the future, we still have the code here.

Comment: @Kristina So you can run the code here instead of going somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css selector is not specific enough

`.weather #unit-toggle` overrides `.toggle`'s `left` property.
try `#unit-toggle.toggle`

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpvOvV

Answer (score 1):

Your previous selector is more specific so to balance it you have to use this:

```
#unit-toggle.toggle {
    left: 15px;
}
```